# 「何かあるごとに」Not quite sure what it means or how to translate

Tags: grammar, meaning, expressions

What does **「何かあるごとに」** mean in this sentence, the best i can come up with is, "every time something happens", but it doesn't seem quite right.

> **何かあるごとに**姉がこうしてくるので「抱擁」しているのですが・・・違いましたか？

context, is that one is hugging the other, and the one getting hugged is slightly flustered.

The best guess i can come up with for the whole sentence is, "each time some happens, a big sister does this, so i'm hugging (you), but... was i wrong?"

Comment: The literal translation "every time something happens" is correct, and makes sense, to a degree, but I feel there's a hidden "at all" attached to "何か", so that it's more like "every time *anything at all* happens".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"何かあるごとに" can be rephrased as "なにかにつけて," which means "taking advantage of any available opportunities, under any excuse possible.  I have difficulty in understanding the given quote. It looks incomplete to me, but I interpret it as;

"Everytime my elder sister does like this, I mean hugs me, So I hug her back. - - Am I wrong?

Comment: "so I'm hugging *you* back"という文脈のようです